# read numbers from file in prolog and sorting

Tags: prolog

how to read numbers from file and sorting that in (prolog programming)

Comment: What have you tried? If this is homework, show us an honest attempt and ask about specific problems you encounter.

Comment: http://www.learnprolognow.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can first try the following, reading multiple lines from the console:

```
?- repeat, read(X), (X==end_of_file, !, fail; true).
1.
X = 1 ;
2.
X = 2 ;

No
```

Explanation: The repeat/0 predicate repeatedly succeeds so that 
read/1 is called over and over. Calling read/1 only stops when end_of_file
has been reached because of the cut that follows it.

Then you can wrap it into a findall/3 and call sort/2:

```
?- findall(X,(repeat, read(X), (X==end_of_file, !, fail; true)),L), sort(L,R).
2.
1.

L = [2, 1],
R = [1, 2]
```

If needed you can use your own sort and enhance the read by a stream argument.

Best Regards